# Prevent banner overflow

Tags: html, css, resize, banner

As you can see in the picture below, my logo/banner is overlapping the body of my site when I zoom in using any browser. It continues to overflow the farther you zoom in.
What would be the best way to keep the banner the same width as the body even after zooming occurs?

HTML:

```
<div class="container1"> <div class="header"><img src="images/banner test.jpg" alt="logo" />
```

CSS:

```
.container1 {
width: 80%;
max-width: 1260px;
min-width: 780px;
margin: 0 auto; 
}

.header {
max-width: 900px;
margin: 0 auto;
}
```

http://i62.tinypic.com/2poum52.jpg

Thanks a lot in advance.

Comment: set `overflow:hidden;` for banner

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add overflow to your div

```
   .header {
        max-width: 900px;
        margin: 0 auto;
        overflow: hidden;
   }
```

Comment: Wow, I could have sworn I tried this before, but that worked. Thanks!